# Derivative of differentiable function can have only discontinuities of 2nd kind

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

A function $f(x)$ may be differentiable on the entire real line, without having continuous derivative. Show that $f'(x)$ can have only discontinuities of second kind.

*Remark: This is actually quite well-known problem in MSE and there are few posts with solution but all of them are similar to each other in the sense that solutions follow the following scheme: they show that the point of discontinuity cannot be *removable discontinuity* and *discontinuity of  first kind*.*

**My approach:** Suppose that $a\in \mathbb{R}$ is the discontinuity of $f':\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $f'(a+0):=\lim \limits_{x\to a+0}f'(x)$ and $f'(a-0):=\lim \limits_{x\to a-0}f'(x)$ exist. Then at least one of them is not equal to $f'(a)$ so WLOG we can assume that $f'(a+0)\neq f'(a)$ and WLOG $f'(a)<f'(a+0)$.

Suppose $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(a)<\lambda<f'(a+0)$. Then by definition of limit one can find $\delta>0$ such that $\forall z\in (a,a+\delta]$ we have $f'(z)>\lambda$. Hence $f'(a)<\lambda<f'(a+\delta)$ and by Darboux's theorem there is $\xi\in (a,a+\delta)$ such that $f'(\xi)=\lambda$. But this is impossible.

Derived contradiction shows us that at least one of the $f'(a-0),f'(a+0)$ does not exist. This means that $a$ is the discontinuity of second kind.

In my solution I do not consider two cases: i) $f'(a+0)=f'(a-0)\neq f'(a)$ and ii) $f'(a-0)\neq f'(a+0)$.

Is my solution and reasoning correct?

Comment: $f’(a+0)$ does equal to $f’(a)$ what notation are you using ?

Comment: @VivaanDaga $f'(a+0)$ is the standard notation for the RHS limit, i.e. $f'(a+0):=\lim \limits_{x\to a+0}f'(x)$

Comment: I think that it is correct.

Comment: @Koro, Thank you so much that you spent some time to my problem.

Comment: @Koro, did you delete your previous comments? I did not read them in detail

Comment: Yes. I thought about the case when Left hand limit exists but right hand limit does not and whether it was being covered in your proof or not. But it is covered I think so I deleted my previous comments. :)

Comment: @Koro, Actually this is a nice remark. But I guess it was covered in my proof. In my proof I just considered the case of RHS limit. But it can be adapted to the LHS limit easily. Which shows us that those limits, i.e. LHS and RHS do not exist at all.

Comment: No. I think you should claim (you have already proved) that "at least" one of LHS or RHS does not exist. Because LHS exists, RHS does not is also a case of 2nd type of discontinuity. Isn't it?

Comment: @Koro, yeah this is also the case of 2nd type discontinuity. But in our problem it is true that both of them do not exist, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122952/discussion-between-zfr-and-koro).

Comment: Your proof is fine. I however prefer to use mean value to conclude that it the left limit of derivative exists then the left hand derivative exists with the same value. Same for right hand side.